# Garage door remote has intermitted problem opening and closing

Tags: garage, garage-door-opener

I have a Chamberlain LiftMaster and multiple remotes which are working intermittently. The garage opens fine from the wall control, however when I pull out of the garage and use the remote it will not close. I have to use the wall control to close the garage, however upon my return the remote works. I previously had a LED light installed but I removed it and I also reset and reprogrammed all my remotes. I observed that once the garage is open from the wall control or by remote, there appears to be some kind of delay in allowing the remote to interact with the garage receiver. I noticed that after a period of time you will hear a click from the garage receiver which coincides with the garage light going off. After this occurs the remote will work but will not respond to any subsequent requests/actions. So pressing it once will result in the garage opening or closing depending on what state it is in, however if you click it again right after nothing happens. Hoping someone has a solution for this.

Comment: Have you replaced your batteries recently?

Comment: You could also try reorienting the antenna on the receiver.

Comment: This exact thing happened on mine, they said it needed a new main board, which was very expensive. So instead, I bought a WiFi enabled switch that came with an Ap that lets me trigger it from my phone. I wired the switch to the manual door switch circuit. Works perfect, and it cost about 1/3 the cost of the main board. It also came with the ability to monitor an input, which I connected to a magnetic switch so that if the door is open, the input is On and the Ap shows me that the door is open. That's a bonus because my wife frequently leaves the door open at night.